# How to convert array of dictionary to array of bytes in wp7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to add array of dictionary in SQLite database attribute of blob type.
but blob take only binary data, so how could I convert dictionary array in binary form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we can use DataContractSerializer in Windowns Phone 8 Libraries

```
    Dictionary<string, string>[] stringlist = new Dictionary<string, string>[5];

    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<String, String>[]));

    byte[] byteArr;

    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, stringlist);
        byteArr = ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Here, stringlist is type of Dictionary array which is converted into array of bytes by using DataContractSerializer.